# Displaying radio buttons using ASP.NET MVC EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using EditorForModel bound to a ViewModel. I have to display a list of radio buttons on my form, but I'm not sure how to do this using Data Annotations. Is this possible? Or can I not use EditorForModel in this case?

My ViewModel can be flexible, as it's only a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and I am manually mapping it to my data access layer.

Answer (score 0):

See this Geekswithblogs [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/08/05/mvc-radiobuttonlist-html-helper.aspx) on a radio button helper.

Also another [one](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/05/26/mvc-2-editor-template-for-radio-buttons.aspx).

A google search will turn up additional resources for radio button  lists in ASP.NET MVC.

Here is some code over at [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/973482), too.

Comment: The first two links are (effectively) broken. They redirect to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom editor template:

```
[UIHint("RenderAsRadioButtonsList")]
public SomeObject ToBeRenderedAsRadioButtons { get; set; }
```

and then, in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates, create the partial view:

```
Views
    /Shared
        /EditorTemplates
            RenderAsRadioButtonsList.cshtml
```